# Javascript dropdown menu delete event bug

Tags: javascript

first of all, I am just a beginner on javascript. and I am trying to coding a todo-list application, I ran into a problem with the deleting future that located in every task. When I try to delete specific  task on the application, the application has to compare the id information and delete the task in the relevant id,but aplication not work well, no matter which task I click, it deletes it sequentially from beginning to end.
I also tried with the for-in loop as a solution, but I still got the same result. Where am I going wrong? can you help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <style>
        .dropdown-toggle::after {
            display:none;
        }

        .task {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card-header">Todo List</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="txtTaskName"
                  id="txtTaskName"
                  class="form-control"
                />
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-primary"
                  id="btnAddNewTask"
                >
                  Ekle
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="card mt-3">
            <div class="card-header">
              <button
                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-sm-right"
                id="btnDeleteTask"
              >
                Temizle
              </button>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="task-list"></ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      dynamicList = [
        { Id: 1, gorevAdi: "Görev 1" },
        { Id: 2, gorevAdi: "Görev 2" },
        { Id: 3, gorevAdi: "Görev 3" },
      ];

      displayTasks();

      function displayTasks() {
        let = ul = document.getElementById("task-list");
        ul.innerHTML = "";
        for (let index of dynamicList) {
          let li = `
            <li class="list-group-item task">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="${index.Id}" class="form-check-input">
                    <label for="${index.Id}" class="form-check-label">${index.gorevAdi}</label>
                </div>

                    <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                        <li><a onclick = "deleteTask(${index.Id})" class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delelte</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i> Edit here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
               
            </li>`;
          ul.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", li);
        }
      }

      document
        .querySelector("#btnAddNewTask")
        .addEventListener("click", newTask);

      document
        .querySelector("#txtTaskName")
        .addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
          if (event.key == "Enter") {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("btnAddNewTask").click();
          }
        });

      function newTask(event) {
        let taskInput = document.querySelector("#txtTaskName");
        if (taskInput.value == "") {
          alert("Todo' ya bir içerik girmelisiniz.");
        } else {
          dynamicList.push({
            Id: dynamicList.lenght + 1,
            gorevAdi: taskInput.value,
          });
          taskInput.value = " ";
          displayTasks();
        }

        event.preventDefault();
      }
      function deleteTask(id) {

        let deletedId;
        for (let i of dynamicList) {
            if (i.id = id) {
                deletedId = i
            }
        }

        dynamicList.splice(deletedId, 1);
        displayTasks()
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this section I add function that create tasks and togle menus on tasks

```
 function displayTasks() {
        let = ul = document.getElementById("task-list");
        ul.innerHTML = "";
        for (let index of dynamicList) {
          let li = `
            <li class="list-group-item task">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="${index.Id}" class="form-check-input">
                    <label for="${index.Id}" class="form-check-label">${index.gorevAdi}</label>
                </div>

                    <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                        <li><a onclick = "deleteTask(${index.Id})" class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delelte</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i> Edit here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>

            </li>`;
          ul.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", li);
        }
      }
```

In this section I create delete task function

```
 }
      function deleteTask(id) {

        let deletedId;
        for (let i of dynamicList) {
            if (i.id = id) {
                deletedId = i
            }
        }

        dynamicList.splice(deletedId, 1);
        displayTasks()
      }
```

Comment: `.splice` expects starting index as the first argument - you're passing in an OBJECT or `undefined` - also `if (i.id = id)` has two issues .... `=` is assignment, you want `==` or `===` ... and, the objects have `Id` not `id` property - try `let deletedId =dynamicList.findIndex(({Id}) => Id === id)` - I'd also change `deletedId` to `deletedIndex` to make the variable name consistent with what it is

Comment: Bro ı cant understandt exactly what I spouse to do, can you be more specific

Comment: nope - IF I wrote an answer, that would be it